# Error Unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, syntax

Ok I've been messing with this code for quite a while now and it keeps saying I have an unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 54. Anyone know what it is and how to fix?

```
// Write the key and activation time to the database as a new row
**LINE 54**   $registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES("$key","$time")") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: could you highlight line 54 please

Comment: I put **LINE 54** in front of line 54

Comment: May be error here...write this way->Values('".$key.",'".$value."')                                    $registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES("$key","$time")") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Now you've had this question answered, forget about MySQL and start learning MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements: you're clearly just starting to learn, so learn the better methods of querying databases, rather than bad methods that you'll have to unlearn later

Comment: One can't stress @MarkBaker's point enough. Please stop concatenating strings to make queries and start using prepared statements already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$registerid = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) 
VALUES('$key','$time')") or die(mysql_error());
```

The other solution is to concatenate your variables, like so:

```
$registerid = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) 
VALUES(" . $key . "," . $time . ")") or die(mysql_error());
```

---

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

There was Syntax error. The code was broken by the use of double quotes near `VALUES("$key","$time")`

```
$registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES('$key','$time')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It happens. Thats why we are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

your insert query looks like it has been broken by the `"` php is smart enough can read its variable inside the `"` quotes then no need to wrap you variables in the `"` when they are already opened

```
 $registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp)
 VALUES($key,$time)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct line 54 is

> $registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey
>   (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES(\"$key\",\"$time\")") or
>   die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

```
**LINE 54**   $registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES(\"$key\",\"$time\")") or die(mysql_error());
```

Escape your quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the culprit. If you break off a string to insert variables you need to concatenate them

Solution A:

```
$registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES('".$key."','".$time."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Solution B

```
$registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES('$key','$time')") or die(mysql_error());
```

And please don't use deprecated functions like mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
$registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (`uniqueid`,`timestamp`) VALUES('$key','$time')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES("$key","$time")") or die(mysql_error());
```

Replace with:

```
$registerid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloadkey (uniqueid,timestamp) VALUES('" . $key . "','" . $time . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```